# 13.10: Can't log in

Tags: 13.10, lightdm

So I've tried just about every fix I could find out there, but I still can't log in to my account. When I enter the correct password, the screen goes black for about a second, the cursor disappears, and after another second it brings me right back to the login screen. I can log in to the guest account without any issues, but not the one I normally use. For reference, I've tried all these possible solutions:

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
```

Nothing happens. Exact same issue.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge cinnamon*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Tells me cinnamon is not installed. Issue continues.

```
ls -lah
chown "username:username" .Xauthority
```

"username" = my username. No errors, but the issue persists.

```
ls -ld /tmp
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
```

Still no errors, but no sign of being able to log in.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Works in the background for about a second and.... nothing. Issue persists.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Update of Nvidia drivers proceeds with no errors, but it does nothing to correct my issue.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Kicks me back to the login screen but the issue persists.

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
```

Nothing happens.

Reinstall Ubuntu (twice.)
Nothing changed either time.

EDIT: Contents of /var/log/xorg.0.log available at http://paste.ubuntu.com/7063767/

Anyone have some Ideas?

Comment: try to purge nvidia and install it via bumblebee.Command to purge all the nvidia packages `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`.Now try to login.Still shows the same black screen then remove xorg.conf file by running `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: Tried to purge nvidia using the command, but it goes through all the related packages and says none of them are installed, so not removed. I'm still here in the guest account. The xorg.conf file doesn't exist, so isn't removed.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/xorg.0.log` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and edit the links into your question? Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able with the clean installation without installing anything else (no nvidia, nothing) be able to log in?

Comment: How do I access those files from the guest account? I have not been able to log in with the clean installation. Only into the guest account.

Comment: Hi Sorou,
Did you figure out a solution? I am in the same boat.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly but is the caps-lock on on your keyboard when you try to enter your password? also, perhaps your keyboard has malfunctioned. Try plugging in a different keyboard.

Comment: A small alert appears if you have your caps lock on while typing in the password. I've also tried intentionally using the wrong password and it just tells me the password is incorrect. It only takes me back to the login screen after I've already entered the correct password.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching into CLI by pushing ctrl + alt + f1 and see if you can log in that way.  From there try switching back to the GUI using startx or lightdm start